# Django rest framework: automatically create a url for each field of a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, large-data

I have large table of data (~30 Mb) that I converted into into a model in Django. Now I want to have access to that data through a REST API.

I've successfully installed the Django REST framework, but I'm looking for a way to automatically create a URL for each field in my model. My model has about 100 fields, and each field has about 100,000 entries.

If my model is named Sample,

```
models.py

class Sample(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...97 more fields...
```

then I can access the whole model using Django REST framework like this:

```
urls.py
class SampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ( **100 fields**)

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'sample', SampleViewSet)
```

But of course my browser can't load all of that data in a reasonable amount of time. I could manually make a different class and URL for each field, but there must be a better way... I want to be able to go to my_site.com/sample/year (for example) and have it list all of the years in JSON format, or my_site.com/sample/name and list all the names, etc. 
Please help me figure out how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do that using a custom viewset route.

You have this:

```
class ModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    @list_route()
    def sample_field(self, request):
        desired_field = request.data.get('field', None)
        if not desired_field:
            return response # pseudocode

        values = Model.objects.all().values_list(desired_field, flat=True)
        # serialize this for returning the response
        return Response(json.dumps(values))  # this is an example, you might want to do something mode involved
```

You will be able to get this from the url:

```
/api/model/sample_field/?field=foo
```

This extra method on the viewset will create a new endpoint under the samples endpoint. Since it's a list_route, you can reach it using /sample_field.

So following your code, it would be:

`mysite.com/sample/sample_field/?field='year'`

for example.

There are many interesting details in your question, but with this sample I think you might able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a little bit confused about how the URL mapping will work following your code. Do I also need to change this code?

    `router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'sample', SampleViewSet)`

Comment: No need to use change the router registry. The URL is derived from the method name decorated with the list_route decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pagination. You can do it in almost the same way as in you question. Pagination in django lets you divide the results into pages. You don't have to display all the entries in the same page. I think this is the best option for you.

Refer django documentation on pagination:
[Pagination in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/)

Comment: the problem he is having is different. he needs to pluck a specific field from all of his samples and get them all at once.